# how to add circle to existing mesh by python script

Tags: python, scripting

if i want one object with 10 circles inside it, i can create first one, then enter edit mode of it, then create remain 9 circles, which seems like design mode programming.

how can i do this at once something like:

```
mes = bpy.data.meshes.new(name+"Mes")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name+"Obj", mes)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
for i in (range(1..10):
    mes.primitive_circle_add(...)       # <- will not work ???
mes.update()
```

is `from_pydata` only allowed function for mesh object or there is a way to draw circle in it.

Comment: `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(...)` is what you were looking for  in example above.

Comment: @batFINGER no, that line was just 'pseudocode', i was looking for your answer below :) thanks, it has everything i need, especially moving verts inside bmesh-geom i would not figure out myself.

Comment: Just noticed you wanted concentrics, edited code in answer accordingly.  Can also multiply `scalar * v.co` to scale coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html)**

Suggest getting to know bmesh as soon as possible.   There are a number of create primitive operators in `bmesh.ops` including [`bmesh.ops.create_circle(..)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_circle)

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Circles")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Circles", me)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
#new bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
# load in a mesh
bm.from_mesh(me)

for i in range(1, 10):
    # create circle
    geom = bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm, 
                segments=16, 
                diameter=1 / i)
    verts = geom["verts"]
    # translate verts
    for v in verts:
        v.co.z += i / 4

# write back to mesh
bm.to_mesh(me)
# make context
scene.objects.active = obj
obj.select = True
scene.update()
```

[Note there is a more involved example on bmesh API re circles](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#operator-example)